# NoSQL data model design for players in a game

Tags: database, firebase, nosql, dart

I am modelling a game which can be single (player1 vs player2) or double (pair 1 vs pair 2, where each pair contains 2 players) and each game has a score. The game is group and date based e.g. Group A on `date_n` can contain `n` games, on `date_m` can contain `m` games. In firestore, I use a `game` collection which looks like this:

```
game = 
{
    date : '2019-01-14',
    groupId : 'abcd',
    player1 : 'Bob',
    player2 : 'John', // can be null
    player3 : 'Tony',
    player4 : 'Mike', // can be null
    score1 : 15,
    score2 : 21
}
```

To easily query the ranking statistics (see below), I separate the game score int to two fields `score1` and `score2` where the final score would simply be `score1:score2`. Note that `player2` and `player4` are `null` for a single game, whereas `player1` and `player3` are never null/empty.

In a relational database e.g. SQL, it's just the same thing but in a game table.
So far so good I think! The tricky part is when querying and writing game statistics for each **player** and **pair**. The player/pair ranking stats are also time-range based e.g. **daily/monthly/annually/alltime**. To simplify, let's say I just want to rank each player/pair based on how many games each player/pair played and how many games each player/pair won.

In firestore, to avoid nesting the data too deeply, I use 8 collections:

```
playerdailystats
playermonthlystats
playerannuallystats
playeralltimestats
pairdailystats
pairmonthlystats
pairannuallystats
pairalltimestats
```

and they all have the same structure, using `playerdailystats` as an example:

```
playerdailystats = 
    {
        date : '2019-01-14',
        groupId : 'abcd',
        Bob : {
            played : 1,
            won : 0,
        },
        John : {
            played : 1,
            won : 0
        },
        Tony : {
            played : 1,
            won : 1
        },
        Mike : {
            played : 1,
            won: 1
        }
   }
```

where each player field (e.g. `Bob`) is an **map** itself; and for monthly/annually stats collections the **first day of the month/year** will be used for the `date` field. For player/pair `alltimestats` collection, I chose a const date randomly e.g. 1983-10-06 for the date field though it doesn't require a date field but it's added in order to **reuse the same query** on all these stats collections (see below). For pairstats collections, just like player stats collections, each pair field is still a map though instead of using a player's name, I use a pair name which is combined of two player's names in the form of `name1,name2`. Since this can be in a form of either `player1Name,player2Name` or `player2Name,player1Name`, I sort two names first then use combined the names separated by comma.

Now I can use a single function to query the stats for daily, monthly, annually and alltime for each group with a given date because all these stats collections have the same structure. On the UI, it only shows one time-range stats at a time e.g. monthly. So the query function is like this (I am using dart but the language doesn't matter):

```
Stream<Map<DateTime, List<Ranking>>> getRanking(String groupId, String collection) {
   return Firestore.instance.collection(collection)
      .where('groupId', isEqualto: groupId)
  // why alltime stats collection need a date field.
      .orderBy('date', descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .take(5) // only show the latest 5 ranking.
      .map((snaoshot){
        // deserialize the data into domain models and return the result.
    //in each stats collection, any fields that are not 'groupId' and not 'date' must be a stat field for a player or pair
       });  
}
```

The querying part isn't bad either since only one stats collection will queried at any time. Now the part that I think is potentially problematic: add a new game!
Any time adding a new *single or double* game for a given group, it doesn't only mean updating the `game` collection, but also mean updating **ALL** 4 or 8 stats collections of the group to keep the stats synchronised. Though I can again use one function to update all 8 collections due to their identical structure. The function for adding a new game result looks like this:

```
Future<OperationResultBase> addNewGameResult(GameResult gameResult) async {
    try {
      // first add the game result
      await Firestore.instance
          .collection(FirestoreName.GAMES)
          .add(gameResult.toJson());

      // then update player daily stats
      await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
          gameResult,
          FirestoreName.PLAYERDAILYSTATS,
          gameResult.date,
          RankingBase.parseGameResultToPlayerRanking);

      // then update player monthly stats
      await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
          gameResult,
          FirestoreName.PLAYERMONTHLYSTATS,
          _firstDayOfTheMonth(gameResult.date),
          RankingBase.parseGameResultToPlayerRanking);

      // then update player annually stats
      await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
          gameResult,
          FirestoreName.PLAYERANNUALLYSTATS,
          _firstDayOfTheYear(gameResult.date),
          RankingBase.parseGameResultToPlayerRanking);

      // then update player all time stats
      await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
          gameResult,
          FirestoreName.PLAYERALLTIMESTATS,
          DateTime(1983, 10, 6), // use a special const date
          RankingBase.parseGameResultToPlayerRanking);

      // if it's a double game,
      if (gameResult.isDoubleGame) {
        // then update pair daily stats
        await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
            gameResult,
            FirestoreName.PAIRDAILYSTATS,
            gameResult.date,
            RankingBase.parseGameResultToPairRanking);

        // then update pair monthly stats using 1st day of the month.
        await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
            gameResult,
            FirestoreName.PAIRMONTHLYSTATS,
            _firstDayOfTheMonth(gameResult.date),
            RankingBase.parseGameResultToPairRanking);

        // then update pair annually stats using 1st date of the year.
        await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
            gameResult,
            FirestoreName.PAIRANNUALLYSTATS,
            _firstDayOfTheYear(gameResult.date),
            RankingBase.parseGameResultToPairRanking);

        // then update pair all time stats using const date.
        await _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
            gameResult,
            FirestoreName.PAIRALLTIMESTATS,
            DateTime(1983, 10, 6),
            RankingBase.parseGameResultToPairRanking);
      }

      return OperationResultBase.ok();
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      return OperationResultBase(success: false, message: error.message);
    }
  }
```

The `_updateRankingStatsNoTransaction` function looks like this:

```
Future<void> _updateRankingStatsNoTransaction(
      GameResult gameResult, // contain game result data
      String collection, // which collection to update
      DateTime date, // which date
 // a function to parse game result to ranking map for a player or pair.
// hence I have two such parser functions, one for player, one for pair.
      Map<String, Map<String, int>> Function(
              GameResult, Map<String, Map<String, int>>)
          rankingParser) async {
    // firstly check whether there is a document already for the given group
   // and date.

   // if not, create a new document and insert the parsed ranking stats.

   // if yes, update the existing document to store the updated ranking stats.
}
```

My questions:

1. Obviously I want to know whether there is a better way of doing all this. I feel like there needs a balance between making querying data and writing data relatively easy. Some way of designing the data structure could lead to querying easier but writing harder, or writing easier but querying harder.
2. Would a relational or graph database suit this kind of problem better? I did try to use SQL to model this before though can't find the code anymore. But I did have to use a lot of long nested queries/views/store procedures, which feels ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I don't think you need 8 root level stats collections. Instead one stats collection and create those 8 as sub collections. Keep in mind that you can't query across the sub collections. (Anyway you can't query across the root level collections too. So, you are not losing anything)

```
stats
     playerdaily
        {
        date : '2019-01-14',
        groupId : 'abcd',
        Bob : {
            played : 1,
            won : 0,
        },
        John : {
            played : 1,
            won : 0
        },
        Tony : {
            played : 1,
            won : 1
        },
        Mike : {
            played : 1,
            won: 1
        }
     playermonthly
        ...
     playerannually
     playeralltime
     pairdaily
     pairmonthly
     pairannually
     pairalltime
```

```
games
  gameid {
    date : '2019-01-14',
    groupId : 'abcd',
    player1 : 'Bob',
    player2 : 'John', // can be null
    player3 : 'Tony',
    player4 : 'Mike', // can be null
    score1 : 15,
    score2 : 21
}
```

Write a cloud function with create trigger. Every time a new game added, update these stats sub collection. Firestore is not great in aggregating. You have to take care of that.

I don't see why you need a graph database for this. If you need to find relationship between players and games, then it could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for this. Maybe I am not understanding this but using one root collection with 8 sub-collection doesn't fundamentally change how this is done, does it?

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't change fundamentally how you are doing, but gives you a better schema structure. I felt that was the question (how to improve the data structure).

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I would do something similar as you do now. Since firestore is not good at query at all, I agree we should write harder.

If your query is really complicated and need to be in relational-like, I guess the answer is SQL-like solution.